# データフレームのnanとNoneの比較

Tags: python, pandas

PythonのPandasで、2つのデータフレームraw1, raw2があり、raw1のx1,x2とraw2のy1,y2を比べて違うもの(x1!=y1 or x2!=y2)のみを出力したいと考えていますが、片方は欠損値がnan, もう一方はNoneになっており、比較ができなくて困っています。

`raw1 = raw1.where((pd.notnull(raw1)), None)`
として、nanをNoneに寄せることはできるのですが、

```
out = pd.merge(raw1, raw2, on='key')
out = out[(out.x1 is not out.y1)]
```

としてもエラーは出ないものの、x1,y1ともにNoneのものが残ってしまい困っています。

また、最後に
`out = out[(out.x1 is not out.y1) or (out.x2 is not out.y2)]`
として違うもののみを出力するところもうまくいきません。
以下のエラーが出ます。
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

詳しい方、教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

**追記**

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({'col_0': ["zero", "one", None],
                    'col_1': np.arange(3, 6),
                    'col_2': ("6", "7", None)},
                   index=['row_0', 'row_1', 'row_2'])
out = x[(x.col_0 is not x.col_2)]
```

とすると、
`KeyError: True`
となり、
`out = x[(x.col_0 != x.col_2)]`
はエラーは起きませんが、outとxが全く同じになってしまう（＝全くフィルターが掛かっていない）ということになります。

**そもそもNaNをNoneに寄せるというのが正しいのか気になります。**
**NoneをNaNに寄せるのはNaNを含む列が数値じゃないと成り立たないので、やはりNaNをNoneに寄せるほうが正しい、ということでよいのでしょうか。それともNoneとNaNのまま比べられる方法もあるのでしょうか？**

**実行環境**
Windows 10
Python 3.7

Comment: 文章とかコードの断片だけでは答えられる人は少ないでしょう。[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)を参考に誰でも再現・検証できるソースコードを追記してください。エラーやおかしな状況が発生しているなら、その詳細も一緒に。

Comment: 頂いたリンクを参考に、追加します。

Comment: 追記いたしました。

Comment: まだコードの断片ですね。この辺のようにDataFrameを作るまたは元になるcsvファイルとかから全体を用意してください。[pandasで欠損値NaNを除外（削除）・置換（穴埋め）・抽出](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-nan-dropna-fillna/), [Pandasメモ ~None, np.nan, 空文字について~](https://qiita.com/kenchin110100/items/4ce98eeabdbd9806a44c), [Working with missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html), [Python（pandas）を使ってテーブル間の差分を取り出す](https://quzee.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/08/13/172151), [Compare two DataFrames and output their differences side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17095101/9014308) ちなみに最初にDataFrameを作る際にNaNかNoneに統一しても駄目なのですか？

Answer (score 2):

[こちらの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53344904) が参考になります。

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from operator import is_not

x = pd.DataFrame({'col_0': ["zero", "one", None],
                  'col_1': np.arange(3, 6),
                  'col_2': ("6", "7", None)},
                  index=['row_0', 'row_1', 'row_2'])
print(x)

out = x.iloc[np.where(np.vectorize(is_not)(x.col_0, x.col_2))]
print(out)
```

**出力結果**

```
      col_0  col_1 col_2
row_0  zero      3     6
row_1   one      4     7
row_2  None      5  None

      col_0  col_1 col_2
row_0  zero      3     6
row_1   one      4     7
```

**追記**

> そもそもNaNをNoneに寄せるというのが正しいのか気になります。NoneをNaNに寄せるのはNaNを含む列が数値じゃないと成り立たないので、やはりNaNをNoneに寄せるほうが正しい、ということでよいのでしょうか。それともNoneとNaNのまま比べられる方法もあるのでしょうか？

比較処理を関数化する方法が考えられます。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = pd.DataFrame({'col_0': ['zero', 'one', np.nan],
                  'col_1': np.arange(3, 6),
                  'col_2': ('6', '7', None)},
                  index=['row_0', 'row_1', 'row_2'])
print(x)

def f(a, b):
  return (
    False if all(x in (None, np.nan) for x in (a, b))
    else (a != b))

out = x.iloc[np.where(np.vectorize(f)(x.col_0, x.col_2))]
print(out)

=>
      col_0  col_1 col_2
row_0  zero      3     6
row_1   one      4     7
row_2   NaN      5  None

      col_0  col_1 col_2
row_0  zero      3     6
row_1   one      4     7
```